# Access refresh back end linked table to excel

Tags: vba, hyperlink, backend

My back end database has a linked table to an Excel spreadsheet which I need to programmably update from my front end database.  I have spent the most part of a day trying to sort it out without success can someone please point me in the right direction.

Roger

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from all Excel files in a folder, using VBA, like this.

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Now, if you just want to refresh links to Excel files, you can try this.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Const strPath As String = "C:\your_path_here\" 'Directory Path
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

     'Loop through the folder & build file list
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
    While strFile <> ""
         'add files to the list
        intFile = intFile + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
        strFileList(intFile) = strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
     'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'cycle through the list of files & link to Access
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        strFileList(intFile), strPath & strFileList(intFile), True, ""
         'Check out the TransferSpreadsheet options in the Access
         'Visual Basic Help file for a full description & list of
         'optional settings
    Next
    MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " Files were Linked"

End Sub
```

Notice the difference between `acImport` and `acLink`.

Comment: Now I am confused?  You obviously updated your solution and it has changed in that you are now linking directly to the excel spreadsheet and seem to be linking the data to the front end database.  My problem relates to updating the back end database as I have technical problems getting at the excel file from the front end dbs. Are you implying that you can't update and excel link in the back end db?  Thanks for what you have done so far.

Comment: Can you describe EXACTLY what you are trying to do?  I thought I gave you a solution that does what you asked for, both times, but it seems like you want something else.  Do you store data in Access or Excel?  Do you manipulate data in Access or Excel.

Comment: I have two Access databases, a front end db which has forms and reports and gets distributed to four users and a back end db to which the front end dbs are linked.  I have no problem with these links.  The back end db has multiple tables one of which is linked to an excel spreadsheet.  This is the table that I am trying to programmatically update from the front end dbs.  Otherwise it means someone has to open up the back end db and manually update the table.